# NodeJs server, I cant return data

Tags: node.js, server, backend

I try to get datas from mongoDb in my nodeJs server, and i cant return my datas.I tryed to return it by res.send() but it told me that .send() is not a function so I alose tryed to just return my datas but the function is in  a loop

there is my code:

```
require('dotenv').config();
var http = require('http');
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');
const client = new MongoClient(process.env.MONGO_URL);
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();
app.use(cors())


var server = http.createServer(async function (req, res) {
    let response
    await client.connect();
    console.log('Conenction OK!');
    const db = client.db('ArtisanTest')
    const collection = db.collection('phones')

   if (req.url == '/') {
        
        ...
    
    }
    else if (req.url == "/create") {

        ...
    
    }
    else if (req.url == "/read") {
        try {
            const read = (await collection.find()).toArray()
            response = await read
        } 
        catch (e) { throw e;}   
    
    }
    else if (req.url == "/update") {

        ...
    
    }
    else if (req.url == "/delet") {

        ... 
    
    }

    return response

});

server.listen(5000);

console.log('Node.js web server is running at port 5000.')
```

(its about my /read case)

Can someone help me please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to use `node:http` server [outgoing message](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#class-httpoutgoingmessage), use [express server](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html)

```js
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello World!')
})

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening on port 3000`)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue arose because of the way you are declaring the routes.
Here, the return is going synchronously while the response awaits the response from the database. For resolving the error at this instance you may try returning the response from there. Try the below code

```js
...
    else if (req.url == "/read") {
        try {
            const read = (await collection.find()).toArray()
            response = await read
            return res.send(response)
        } 
        catch (e) { throw e;}   
    
    }
...
```

Also, you may want to use `res.json()` for returning the objects.

Comment: thanks for you advice i just tryed it but i still told  me that: return res.send(response) TypeError: res.send is not a function